# Is it possible to drag and drop an item into a specific position in a listbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have three listboxes in a Windows Form. The first one will remain the same. I want to drag and drop items from the third one into the second one in order to match it with a specific element of the first one. So for example the first listbox has 10 elements, second is empty, third has 10 elements. I want to drag the second element of the third listbox into the fifth position in the second one (that was empty), so it matches with the fifht element of the first listbox. That makes sense? Can it be done? How? (not asking for the entire code, just want to know if it is possible, and may be some tips on how to do it)

Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If the second listbox is empty, then how can you drag an item into the 5th position in that listbox? There is no *5th position* in an empty list. In order to have a 5th position, there have to be at least 4 items already in the listbox, and that can't be possible with an empty listbox.

Comment: All right then. Is there another tool in Windows Form, similar to the listbox, where i can do it?

Comment: There is nothing I'm aware of that will allow you to drag something into the 5th position without having 4 items before it. Nothing I know of allows you to just invent an arbitrary position in a list that doesn't contain items before that position. There probably isn't one, because what you're asking doesn't seem logical. The only way to do this is to have the user drag an item into the first position, and then the second, and then the third, and so forth.

Comment: actually its more of a hack that i thought. make it look like empty. make items inside `""` then if it is placed there overwrite the value with the dragged value. just a little bit busy to explore

Comment: Ok, thanks. So lets say the second listbox has 10 elements too. Can i drop an item into its fifht position and replace it? any tips?

Comment: Yes, thanks Gab Llorico! im thinking about that solution.

Comment: You can use Hittest to find out about the drop position.

Answer (score 1):

Well, i don't know if it is the best way to do it, but it's working. I adapted a code for reordering a listbox with drag and drop.

```
  private void LstBox3_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        if (lstBox3.SelectedItem == null) return;
        lstBox2.DoDragDrop(lstBox3.SelectedItem, DragDropEffects.All);
    }





    private void LstBox2_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {

        Point point = lstBox2.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        int index = lstBox2.IndexFromPoint(point);
        if (index < 0) index = lstBox2.Items.Count - 1;            
        object data1 = lstBox3.SelectedItem;
        lstBox2.Items.RemoveAt(index);
        lstBox2.Items.Insert(index, data1);


    }



    private void LstBox2_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
    }
```